# Codeception __HALT_COMPILER(); not found

Tags: codeception

Any idea? I use 5.6.21 on mac with vagrant

[UnexpectedValueException]

internal corruption of phar "/private/var/tmp/C3yig9xM.tar" (__HALT_COMPILER(); not found)

Comment: Can be that it is only on api testing with code coverage